# How to merge 2 images under linux console (via sh script)

Tags: shell-script, images, image-manipulation

I have jpeg image on the server from IP camera. This is every 1-second snapshot. Because of privacy, I need to cover the closest balcony.

[image]

I was prepared a cover png image. Is it possible to make a shell script to merge images? Exactly on yourself or using pixel coordinates? Input file is jpeg, the cover is png, output file must be jpeg.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why downvote. I would recommend to you use blur from console with imagemagick: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#blur. Hopes it's helpful for you.

Comment: Please, let me know if it helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I am looking for, but it will be a lot of effort and work to understand how it works because I never use this tool.

Comment: It's not difficult. I used this tool about 2 years ago but for another tasks. I'm glad to listen this tool is helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For using blur feature, you should create black&white image with same size as source image (black hold image untouched, white-blure).

Black&white image:
[image]

Bluring:

```
convert main.jpeg blur2.png -compose blur -define compose:args=10 -composite main_blured.jpeg

compose:args=<arg>    opacity of bluring
```

Result image:
[image]

Also it's possible to solve this issue with [`-flatten` feature](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#layer_pins):

```
convert main.jpeg -page +275+580 blur.png -flatten main_blured.jpeg

-page +275+580     start position of "blurring"/flattening image main.jpeg
```

Result image is (it's possible play with position coordinates for more clear image):

[image]

Comment: Thank you Yurij. I must use blur function. This image is in sunny day and daytime. At night, the image looks different. I'm currently installing virtual server and go to try it.

Comment: You are genius. Thank you. All works. It takes some time to process, but I reduce camera to download to 5 seconds.

Comment: You are welcome. It was interesting task. Thanks for that too!

Comment: I have my mistake, cron was run every one minute another infinite loop, the server is overloaded. Currently, everything looks OK. See https://kamery.lemo.cz/masarykova/

Comment: Nice picture! Great work! All seems OK. Thanks again for interesting task!